# The type or namespace name 'ThreadPoolTimer' could not be found

Tags: c#

I'm tring to use the class `ThreadPoolTimer`. But I got an error

> "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ThreadPoolTimer' could not
>   be found".

Following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace learning
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ......
            ThreadPoolTimer Timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ready to delay 5s");
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                }
            }, delay);
   ......
}
```

Comment: ThreadPoolTimer is not for Console application, use System.Threading.Timer instead. ThreadPoolTimer is for Windows Store app or UWP app.

Comment: thanks. i will try it later